# Disable Case Resolution Action on form load

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to disable the ability to resolve a case in CRM unless a couple fields have data.  I would like to gray out the case resolution action and was wondering if anyone knew how to do this on the form Load.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code on the OnLoad event of the Case form:

```
var menuItem = document.getElementById('_MIresolve');
if (menuItem)
  menuItem.disabled = 1;
```

You can Ctrl+N any CRM page in order to be able to view its source code and figure out ids of controls.